# From Orthogonal vectors to Useful Bivector

Tags: signal-processing, information-theory, exterior-algebra, geometric-algebras

If we have set of orthogonal vectors (X) can we form a set of orthogonal bivectors from that set?

I am trying to find if there is a way to get 'more information' from an orthogonal matrix by some sort of manipulation (like the exterior product). If I consider uncorrelated variable as orthogonal matrix can independent variable mean something else?

Additionally, may be I can put it this way: If I have a model of the orthogonal set of vectors which have a unknown factor due to noise, can we learn more on the space of bivectors?

Comment: That is a very vague question imo. Is it correct to rephrase it as follows: given a vector space $V$, let's say over the real numbers, and a bilinear form $b : V\times V \to \Bbb R$, what kind of structure now lives naturally on the exterior square $V\wedge V$? I believe the answer is, in that case, that it naturally has the structure of a Lie algebra, known as $\mathfrak s\mathfrak o$ associated to that bilinear ( quadratic) form. Is this the type of thing you are looking for?

Comment: There is also an inner product on it, btw. It is given by the $2\times 2$-determinant $\langle v_1 \wedge v_2, w_1\wedge w_2\rangle = \begin{vmatrix}\langle v_1,w_1\rangle &\langle v_2,w_1\rangle\\\langle v_1,w_2\rangle&\langle v_2,w_2\rangle \end{vmatrix}$.

Comment: The rephrase appears to be correct but it appear to be very broad. If the V, which is complex but made up of sinusoidal is the problem well defined?

Comment: Can you share some references involving the notion of inner product of two bivectors?

Comment: @Anirban No, I have no reference, this question came I was looking for reference and did not find any.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the set of vectors $X$ consists of mutually orthogonal vectors, then all bivectors formed from products of elements in this set are mutually orthogonal.

How can we demonstrate this?  Consider $a, b, c, d \in X$, $b \neq a$ and $c \neq d$.  Then $ab$ and $cd$ are bivectors, using the geometric product.  Now consider the product $abcd$.

If $a = c$, then $abad = -aabd$ by orthogonality, and we get $-|a|^2bd$.  This only produces a scalar if $b = d$ also; otherwise, we get another bivector (the commutator product).

If $a \neq c$ but $b = d$, the logic is the same as above.

If $a \neq c$ and $b \neq d$, then all four vectors are orthogonal, and we get a grade-4 multivector--one with no scalar part.

Thus, $\langle abcd \rangle_0 \neq 0$ only when $a=c$ and $b =d$, and thus when $ab = cd$.  This, to me, is just like the notion of orthogonality in vectors, so I think we can use the same word for this.

I used only the elements of the same set to help restrict some of the cases to be considered, but since bivectors form their own vector space, that should be enough to argue that this notion of bivector orthogonality is just like that of vector orthogonality.